# No wifi adapter found Intel 9560

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

I am running ubuntu 19.10 for a while with no issues. After restart my Wifi Adapter cannot be found.

I updated all my drivers to the latest firmware and the issues are not resolved.

`dmesg | grep iwl
[ 3.753471] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[ 4.227490] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:52:00.0 failed with error -110`

`lspci -nn | grep -i network
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)`

Comment: Just FYI: You are using an _Intel WiFi 6 AX200_ network adapter.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? What is your kernel version? `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.